# Traefik - simple proxy pass configuration

Tags: docker, docker-compose, proxy, reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm stucked with a simple configuration of Traefik to pass requests from my IP to my application.

Supposing my ip is `192.0.0.1`, I need to pass all requests from this host to my application that is running inside this server on `0.0.0.0:8001`. I've seen various configurations but nothing works :/. I don't know what am I doing wrong and I want to understand why and the operation of Traefik.

As we are working with containers, I understand that Traefik will pass the requests from your container to another, right?

What I'm doing is:

`traefik-local.toml`

```ini
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.web]
    address = ":80"

[api]
insecure = true

[log]
level = "DEBUG"

[accessLog]

[providers]
  [providers.docker]
    exposedByDefault = false
```

`compose.yaml`

```yaml
services:
  backend:
    build: . # In my Dockerfile context I'm just copying the app and installing requirements
    command: |
      uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001
    # Doubts
    # expose: I need to expose the port 8001 to Traefik see the app?
    # ports: Could I expose the ports using this property instead of `expose`?
    # networks: I need to leave the application and traefik in same network? Could't leave this in default network?
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.backend.rule=Host(`192.168.0.1`)"

  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.10.1
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - ./traefik-local.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
```

I'm sure that we need to link in Traefik config to tell him "Hey, get this requests incoming from `192.168.0.1` and pass to `0.0.0.0:8001`, but I don't know how!

I don't know if we need to specific the ports or simply redirect to container that is serving the backend...

Example with nginx config

```bash
location / {
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8001;
}
```

In exactly this that I need to do, but using the Traefik.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me

```yaml
services:
    backend:
        ...
        labels:
        ...
         - "traefik.http.services.backend.loadbalancer.server.port=8001"
```